# How to hide inner view completely when superview height constant is set to zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview, autolayout

[image]

As you can see, I have  a UIView(red color) that has constraints - leading, bottom, width and height. All set to default(1000) priorities except height(999). Inside this UIView are three UIButtons those have constraints - leading, top, width and height. 
All set to default(1000) priorities except height (2). So that superview's height can override the innerviews height. 
At the click of orange button. I set UIView's height constant to 0.

**And the result is this - in pic below. At bottom you can see content(text) is not compressed to hide itself. What should I do. I have played with vertical compression resistance. Please don't say set buttons to hidden etc.**

[image]

Comment: How are you setting the height constraints of inner views? Are they having constant height constraint? If yes then try by providing the constraint as in a multiplicative factor of super view, that way when super view's height is 0, their height will also be 0. Also top constraint should be felxible like `>=0 , <=c` instead of non-zero value.

Comment: Would setting clipsToBounds=YES on the superview work? It seems like this is what you want

Comment: +1 for @Alex's comment. UIViews by default do not clip subviews, so even if your view's bounds were CGRectZero, you could still see its subviews. (Opinion time: I never really understood why Apple chose to make this the default behavior. Seems very counterintuitive.)

Comment: Both  Gandalf's & Alex's comment are helpfull

Answer (score 0):

// Orange Button Action Clicked

@IBAction func orangeAction(_ sender: Any)
{

redViewHeight.constant = 0

redView.clipsToBounds = true

}

// ClipTo bound : the subview that fits within the bounds of the superview.